# Assigning $_GET values from a URL

Tags: php, get

For the URL (FOO could be anything):

https://www.example.com/_beta!/FOO?first_name=BOB&last_name=SMITH&birthdate=12/07/2007&country_of_citizenship=Cuba

Thought I could do something like:

```
 foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
   $value = trim($value);
   $key = $value;
 echo ' $'.$key.' = '.$value.'<br>'; }
```

Above returns "$FOO = FOO", which seems shouldn't be part of the foreach to start with since it's before the first question mark, and nothing else is returned.

echo $_GET['first_name']; // returns nothing as well.

The URL is being generated by a 3rd party. I have to deal with what's sent me.

1. I'm an idiot and have something wrong in my code
2. I'm doing it completely the wrong way.

Suggestions?

Comment: can you explain how `"The URL is being generated by a 3rd party. I have to deal with what's sent me."` works? How are they sending your (your site) this url? If it is not your server generating this url ( as suggested ) you cannot use GET to process whatever this is.... [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) might be more appropriate?

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to parse a URL that you have as a string value?  Or that the URL is actually your page but a 3rd party could be sending it any query string key/value pairs?  Or something else?  It's not entirely clear what you mean.

Comment: The URL will always be formatted with the exact same vars coming to me, but it's generated on another site in another country.

Comment: your overriding the key with the value in your loop, then outputting, i.e for `country_of_citizenship=Cuba` its going to be `$Cuba = Cuba`

Comment: The URL coming to me will always have the same key/value pairs...

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by removing this line, then verifying the output.

```
$key = $value;
```

Comment: If I forget looping the array and and just try a simple echo $_GET['first_name']; ... no value is displayed and I get an undefined index error That's what has me stumped ... Even if I shorten the URL just for testing purposes to: 
https://www.example.com/_beta!/FOO?first_name=BOB

Comment: I'd guess it's the `!` character in the URL path. I'd also try `parse_url()` or look for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` and manually parse the parameters.

Comment: Changing the URL to remove teh ! has no effect either. Hmmmmm
Looks like I get to work out a way to manually parse everything ...